# How to do calculations on x- y- coordinates from a .csv file

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, for-loop, coordinates

For a few days I can't figure out to solve this problem.

I have generated "coordinates.csv" file of x and y coordinates that looks like this:

```
xcoord,ycoord
112000,556000
112000,555500
112000,555000
112000,554500
112000,554000
112000,553500
```

And I have a certain code that does calculations on a single x and z coordinate. This is a simplified example:

```
#example code stack

x = 2000
y = 3000

new_value = x + y + 10


print(x)
print(y)
```

I want to use the x, y-coordinates from the .csv file instead of (2000,3000). So the code will do the calculations on all of the coordinates in the .csv file. And after that I would like to make a new dataframe with the calculations in the third column. This will look like this:

```
xcoord,ycoord,new_value
112000,556000,668010
112000,555500,667510
112000,555000,667010
112000,554500,666510
112000,554000,666010
112000,553500,665510
```

I think I need a for loop for this but I really can't figure out how to do this. A lot of times I became stuck with the for loop so I hope somewan can help me out.

Thanks for reading and kind regards,

Simon

Here is my code, as asked for. This shows why I think I will need a for loop for this. I tried to implement the method that ThomasO suggested, but that does not seem to work, because P will become a list of coordinates instead of one, but maybe i am wrong. I am still curious for a solution:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import itertools
import math
from pyproj import Transformer
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt
import os
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


## data
land = gpd.read_file('land2.shp')
land = land.to_crs("EPSG:28992")


os.chdir('C:\\Users\\###\\sensoren\\data')
os.getcwd()
wind = pd.read_csv('data_totaal_2.csv', usecols= [ 0, 1,2 , 5],skiprows = 33, names = ['STN','DT','HH','FF'])


## closest point
def min_distance(x, y, iterable):
       list_of_distances = list(map(lambda t: sqrt(pow(t[0]-x,2)+pow(t[1]-y,2)),iterable))
       min_res = min(list_of_distances)
       index_of_min = list_of_distances.index(min_res)
       return iterable[index_of_min]

## check if point is inside triangle
def area(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3):
    return abs((x1 * (y2 - y3) +
                x2 * (y3 - y1) +
                x3 * (y1 - y2)) / 2.0)


def is_inside(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x, y):
    A = area(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3)
    A1 = area(x, y, x2, y2, x3, y3)
    A2 = area(x1, y1, x, y, x3, y3)
    A3 = area(x1, y1, x2, y2, x, y)
    return A == A1 + A2 + A3

## calculate perimeter
def perimeter(points):
    x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3 = *points[0], *points[1], *points[2]
    return (math.hypot(x1-x2, y1-y2) +
            math.hypot(x2-x3, y2-y3) +
            math.hypot(x3-x1, y3-y1))

## barycentric interpolation
def bary_interpol (inter_cor_x1, inter_cor_x2, inter_cor_x3, inter_cor_y1,
                   inter_cor_y2, inter_cor_y3, inter_cor_px, inteR_cor_py,
                   inter_wind_v1, inter_wind_v2, inter_wind_v3):
    W_v1 = ((inter_cor_y2-inter_cor_y3)*(inter_cor_px-inter_cor_x3)+
            (inter_cor_x3-inter_cor_x2)*(inter_cor_py-inter_cor_y3))/((inter_cor_y2-inter_cor_y3)*(inter_cor_x1-inter_cor_x3)+
            (inter_cor_x3-inter_cor_x2)*(inter_cor_y1-inter_cor_y3))
    W_v2 = ((inter_cor_y3-inter_cor_y1)*(inter_cor_px-inter_cor_x3)+
            (inter_cor_x1-inter_cor_x3)*(inter_cor_py-inter_cor_y3))/((inter_cor_y2-inter_cor_y3)*(inter_cor_x1-inter_cor_x3)+
            (inter_cor_x3-inter_cor_x2)*(inter_cor_y1-inter_cor_y3))
    W_v3 = 1 - W_v1 - W_v2
    inter_wind_pv = (W_v1 * inter_wind_v1) + (W_v2 * inter_wind_v2) +  (W_v3 * inter_wind_v3)
    return inter_wind_pv

       
## datum shift
transformer = Transformer.from_crs("epsg:4326", "epsg:28992")

RD_229 = transformer.transform(53.04309, 4.81969) #texelhors_229
RD_235 = transformer.transform(52.91382, 4.79498) #de_kooy_235
RD_242 = transformer.transform(53.25337, 4.94041) #vlieland_242
RD_251 = transformer.transform(53.39335, 5.34623) #terschelling_251
RD_267 = transformer.transform(52.89709, 5.38331) #stavoren_267
RD_277 = transformer.transform(53.40848, 6.19614) #lauwersoog_277

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\###\OneDrive - NIOZ\NIOZ\Pyth\coordinates.csv")

P =  ( df['xcoord'], df['ycoord'])

STN_229_x = RD_229[0]
STN_235_x = RD_235[0]
STN_242_x = RD_242[0]
STN_251_x = RD_251[0]
STN_267_x = RD_267[0]
STN_277_x = RD_277[0]

points = [(RD_229[0],RD_229[1]),(RD_235[0],RD_235[1]),(RD_242[0],RD_242[1]),(RD_251[0],RD_251[1]),(RD_267[0],RD_267[1]),(RD_277[0],RD_277[1])]


## find best triangle or point
triangle_fit = []
for triangle in itertools.combinations(points, 3):
    p1, p2, p3 = triangle
    if is_inside(*p1, *p2, *p3, *P):
       triangle_fit.append(triangle)

triangle_fit.sort(key=perimeter) 


 # Sort by perimeter.

triangle_fit.append(triangle)
triangle_fit.sort(key=perimeter) 
inter_cor = triangle_fit[0]
inter_cor_x1 = inter_cor[0][0]
inter_cor_x2 = inter_cor[1][0]
inter_cor_x3 = inter_cor[2][0]
inter_cor_y1 = inter_cor[0][1]
inter_cor_y2 = inter_cor[1][1]
inter_cor_y3 = inter_cor[2][1]

inter_cor_px = P[0]
inter_cor_py = P[1]


print(inter_cor_x1)
print(inter_cor_x2)
print(inter_cor_x3)
print(inter_cor_y1)
print(inter_cor_y2)
print(inter_cor_y3)

if inter_cor_x1 == STN_229_x:
    STN_v1 = 229
elif inter_cor_x1  == STN_235_x:
    STN_v1 = 235
elif inter_cor_x1  == STN_242_x:
    STN_v1 = 242
elif inter_cor_x1  == STN_251_x:
    STN_v1 = 251
elif inter_cor_x1  == STN_267_x:
    STN_v1 = 267
elif inter_cor_x1  == STN_277_x:
    STN_v1 = 277
else:
    print("no matching stations in v1")

if inter_cor_x2 == STN_229_x:
    STN_v2 = 229
elif inter_cor_x2  == STN_235_x:
    STN_v2 = 235
elif inter_cor_x2  == STN_242_x:
    STN_v2 = 242
elif inter_cor_x2  == STN_251_x:
    STN_v2 = 251
elif inter_cor_x2  == STN_267_x:
    STN_v2 = 267
elif inter_cor_x2  == STN_277_x:
    STN_v2 = 277
else:
    print("no matching stations in v2")
    
if inter_cor_x3 == STN_229_x:
    STN_v3 = 229
elif inter_cor_x3  == STN_235_x:
    STN_v3 = 235
elif inter_cor_x3  == STN_242_x:
    STN_v3 = 242
elif inter_cor_x3  == STN_251_x:
    STN_v3 = 251
elif inter_cor_x3  == STN_267_x:
    STN_v3 = 267
elif inter_cor_x3  == STN_277_x:
    STN_v3 = 277
else:
    print("no matching stations in v1")
    

inter_wind_v1 = wind[wind['STN'] == STN_v1]



inter_wind_v2 = wind[wind['STN'] == STN_v2]


inter_wind_v3 = wind[wind['STN'] == STN_v3]



df_add = inter_wind_v1.FF.add(inter_wind_v1.FF, fill_value=0)



inter_wind_v1 = wind[wind['STN'] == STN_v1].reset_index()
# =============================================================================
# print(f"inter_wind_v1:\n{inter_wind_v1}")
# =============================================================================


inter_wind_v2 = wind[wind['STN'] == STN_v2].reset_index()
# =============================================================================
# print(f"inter_wind_v2:\n{inter_wind_v2}")
# =============================================================================


inter_wind_v3 = wind[wind['STN'] == STN_v3].reset_index()
# =============================================================================
# print(f"inter_wind_v3:\n{inter_wind_v3}")
# =============================================================================

interp = pd.DataFrame(inter_wind_v1['FF']).rename(columns = {'FF':'inter_wind_v1'})
interp['inter_wind_v2'] = inter_wind_v2['FF']
interp['inter_wind_v3'] = inter_wind_v3['FF']
# =============================================================================
# print(interp)
# =============================================================================

def doInterp(inter_wind_v1, inter_wind_v2, inter_wind_v3):
    return bary_interpol (inter_cor_x1, inter_cor_x2, inter_cor_x3, inter_cor_y1,
                   inter_cor_y2, inter_cor_y3, inter_cor_px, inter_cor_py,
                   inter_wind_v1, inter_wind_v2, inter_wind_v3)
interp['inter_wind_pv'] = interp.apply(lambda x: doInterp(x['inter_wind_v1'], x['inter_wind_v2'], x['inter_wind_v3']), axis=1)
print(interp.inter_wind_pv)

wind_time = pd.date_range(start = '1/1/2021 00:01:00', end = '3/13/2022', freq = 'H')

wind_time = pd.DataFrame(wind_time)

print(wind_time)

result = pd.concat([wind_time, interp.inter_wind_pv], axis=1)

print(result)

filepath = Path('C:/Users/###/sensoren/data/out.csv')  

filepath.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)  

result.to_csv(filepath)  

os.makedirs('C:/Users/###/sensoren/data/', exist_ok=True)  





data_s = np.array([
    [RD_229],
    [RD_235],
    [RD_242],
    [RD_251],
    [RD_267],
    [RD_277]
])
data_p = np.array([
    [P]
])


data_i = np.array([
    [ inter_cor_x1, inter_cor_y1],
    [ inter_cor_x2, inter_cor_y2],
    [ inter_cor_x3, inter_cor_y3]
])

x_s, y_s = data_s.T
x_p, y_p = data_p. T
x_i, y_i = data_i. T

ax = land.plot()
plt.scatter( x_p, y_p, c="red")
plt.scatter( x_s, y_s, c="yellow")
plt.scatter( x_i, y_i, c="green")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please update your question with this `for` loop you became stuck on. Also all the code that reads the csv file.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I had simplified the code but here it is. It would be great if you would help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a 'for' loop since you mentioned you wanted a dataframe. In the future, you should provide the code you created and could not get to work.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("numbers.csv")
df['new_value'] = df['xcoord'] + df['ycoord'] + 10
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   xcoord  ycoord  new_value
0  112000  556000     668010
1  112000  555500     667510
2  112000  555000     667010
3  112000  554500     666510
4  112000  554000     666010
5  112000  553500     665510
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Tomas, I tried your method but it did not work it resulted in:
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().